# Adding RPM's to SLES installation DVD

Tags: system-installation, dvd, sles

For a custom installation, I need to add a few rpms from the SDK dvd that comes with the main SLES dvd, onto the main SLES installation dvd. This is because my superiors want 1 single dvd to install SLES from, without the need of extra dvds or ftp-repositories.

As such, I've been trying to accomplish just that.

What I've done is

- extracted the files from the dvds for both the main installation and the SDK
- copied the 3 rpms in question from the SDK to the main installation (/suse/x86_64/)
- added the rpms to packages.*.gz (/suse/setup/descr/packages.*.gz)
- re-calculated the SHA1 sum for the packages.*.gz and entered them in content (/content)

After this, I recreated an ISO image from this modified image.

However, when testing the ISO on a virtual machine, the installation gave me an error saying: `cd:/ Invalid signature Installation aborted`.

In order to fix this, I added `insecure=1` to isolinux.cfg (/boot/x86_64/loader/isolinux.cfg).

This worked, but now I get another error, see the screenshot below.

[image: Installation signature verification failed]

Any suggestions on how to solve this? I've seen people mention adding a custom gpg-key to the initrd, but that is generally for an add-on product. I'm unsure of what to do next with this. :/

---

I've added the following to my autoyast xml file:

```
<scripts>
  <post-scripts config:type="list">
    <![CDATA[
      rpm -i extra/*.rpm > /tmp/extra.log
    ]]>
  </post-scripts>
</scripts>
```

As such, I've added my extra rpm's in a folder called `extra` in my ISO. However, now the installation just fails:

[image: Installation general failure]

---

As per Nils' suggestion, I've added the rpm's to a separate folder on the ISO and install them via the post-script section in an AutoYast profile. The issue I reported with the script above was the result of the `<script><source>...</source></script>` elements missing around the `CDATA`. Adding the part below fixed my problems.

```
<scripts>
  <post-scripts config:type="list">
    <script>
      <source>
        <![CDATA[
          mount /dev/dvd /mnt;
          cd /mnt/extra;
          rpm -i <rpms>;
          cd;
          umount /mnt;
        ]]>
      </source>
    </script>
  </post-scripts>
</scripts>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the rpms into any place you like on the DVD and use a autoyast-post-install-script to install these rpms.

Apart from that I do not see the sense in that request. That system has to be patched after the installation. So this means repositories contacted via network - so the rpms could even be on the network...

Comment: The sense lies in the fact that the DVD can be used by people without the proper knowledge about external repositories. An `Install SLES for our product for dummies`. :P

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, see my updated question. :/

Comment: @ThaMe90 You could have generated that xml-snippet via `yast2`: Automated installation.

Comment: Huh, I never knew that. :O

Answer (score 0):

Granted this is for RHEL, this may help you see what else you need to do: http://www.harkness.co.uk/other/RHEL4_custom_dvd.html

Comment: Nice information, but the whole filesystem on the dvd/ISO is different per OS.